# Auto column number based on other column

Tags: mysql

```
+--------+---------+-----------+-------+
|   id   | title   | parent_id | root  |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------+
|    1   | Lvl-1   |     0     | null  |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------+
|    2   | Lvl-2   |     0     | null  |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------+
|    3   | Lvl-11  |     1     |   1   |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------+
|    4   | Lvl-12  |     1     |   1   |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------+
|    5   | Lvl-121 |     4     |   1   |
+--------+---------+-----------+-------+
```

Here is my problem, every time mysql insert new row, i want a value in  `root` point to the top level parent (actually value in `root` somehow related to value in `parent_id` ).

Based on the table, row with an id = 5, have a parent_id = 4, and row with id = 4 have parent_id = 1, and row with id = 1 have 
parent = 0.So this row get `root` = 1

Basically `root` value come from cascading `parent_id` to the top level (till parent_id = 0)

So in summary, what i want is, when new row is insert, Mysql autoamatically assign value for `root`

So is this can be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily with triggers:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER update_root BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.root = (SELECT root FROM my_table WHERE id = NEW.parent_id);
END; //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I have update my post with added info..Basically i cant simply "SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE root IS NULL", because there is posibility other row also have `root` =null. Like i said `root` got its value from cascading the value of `parent_id`.Can this be done?

Comment: @zerkms its fine now, thx dude..btw got any link i can refer about trigger?

Comment: @Taz: I did not get the question completely, since this structure looks strange for me. But if he said he is ok with my answer - then it's ok :-S

Comment: Sorry now I get it. It does work in this case. I was thinking something else.